# How to backup datastore via cron without datastore_admin?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have backuped datastore via cron using cron.yaml like following

```
- description: My Daily Backup
  url: /_ah/datastore_admin/backup.create?name=BackupToCloud&kind=LogTitle&kind=EventLog&filesystem=gs&gs_bucket_name=whitsend
  schedule: every 12 hours
  target: ah-builtin-python-bundle
```

But
According to google announcement, datastore-admin will go to "deprecated".

> https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/console/datastore-backing-up-restoring

How to backup datastore via cron without datastore_admin?
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scheduled_backups
says only about using gcloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that just the backup/restore functionality based on the datastore-admin will be deprecated, not the datastore-admin itself.

The deprecation note points to the [Managed export and import service](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities) as the recommended replacement alternative.

Exports based on this method can also be scheduled, see [Scheduling an Export](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export). You'll note in that article that a standard env GAE app with a cron service is exactly what the method is based on.

The article is targeted at those apps using the Datastore outside of GAE. Since you already have a GAE app you can just modify your existing backup cron job handler following the example in the article or, if you want to separate it a bit from your main app, you can add a separate service to your app, dedicated to the backup cron job.